Why did Deckard Shaw attack Han in this scene?
In Fast X Deckard Shaw encounters Han at his doorstep, drags him inside, and locks
the door. Meanwhile, Ramsey tries to get in by hacking the door using a
laptop.:

Deckard Shaw: Should have stayed dead. I don't like repeating myself.

Then he attacks him until agency gunmen drive an armored truck into his house
to break in.
Why did Deckard Shaw attack Han in this scene?
